# Customizing reading pane or To/cc/Subject with c#

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am working with Outlook 2010 and the problem i have is that I can't find information how to add buttons to positions displayed in image. Is there any way to achieve it. Searching information about adding buttons here,gave only negative results.

[image: Buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that. If we are talking about the Explorer windows in Outlook, all what you can do is to use Windows API functions for subclassing the Outlook UI. See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/) for more information.

In case of inspector windows you may consider using replacing the inspector UI completely by using Outlook Form Regions. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information (look for the Complete Replacement layout).

I'd suggest creating a Task pane with these buttons instead. Take a look at the following links for more information:

- [Walkthrough: Displaying Custom Task Panes with E-Mail Messages in Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb296010.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How to: Add a Custom Task Pane to an Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

That area in Outlook cannot be customized. As adjacent task pane is the best you can do.